# Change options of dropdown based on label text

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to change the options of an HTML dropdown if the label contains a certain string of text.

For example if the label contained the text 'Object', like it does below, then I would like to change the dropdown options.

So

```
<form id="form-container">
    <ul>
        <li class="gfield" id="field_302_9"><label class="gfield_label" for="input_302_9">Object<span class="gfield_required">*</span></label></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="ginput_container ginput_container_select">
        <select aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" class="large gfield_select" id="input_302_9" name="input_9" tabindex="7">
            <option value="Option 1">
                Option 1
            </option>
            <option value="Option 2">
                Option 2
            </option>
            <option value="Option 3">
                Option 3
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

Would become:

```
<form id="form-container">
    <ul>
        <li class="gfield" id="field_302_9"><label class="gfield_label" for="input_302_9">Object<span class="gfield_required">*</span></label></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="ginput_container ginput_container_select">
        <select aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" class="large gfield_select" id="input_302_9" name="input_9" tabindex="7">
            <option value="Option 4">
                Option 4
            </option>
            <option value="Option 5">
                Option 5
            </option>
            <option value="Option 6">
                Option 6
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

Using jQuery how would this be possible please?

Comment: what is it sense to depends on ?

Comment: You cannot style individual <OPTIONS> using CSS. You need a dropdown replacement library that uses DIVs and can be styled.

Comment: But i haven't suggested changing CSS at all? I provided before and after of HTML and specifically cited achieving this using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the label text using jQuery and change the HTML of the options input.

The label is object?

```
var labelText = $('.gfield_label').text();
var isObject = /Object/.test(labelText);
```

Change the options based on the label

```
if (isObject) {
  var newOptions = '<option value="Option 4">'+
      'Option 4'+
    '</option>'+
    '<option value="Option 5">'+
      'Option 5'+
    '</option>'+
    '<option value="Option 6">'+
      'Option 6'+
    '</option>';

  $('.gfield_select').html(newOptions)
}
```

Working jsbin: http://jsbin.com/sasumivuvi/edit?html,js,console,output

On the other hand, I would recommend not to change the HTML but rather try to write the HTML for given parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are being really vague on how exactly the label gets its value in the first place and how that value is going to affect the select tag, here is a specific approach to give an idea of how the label's value can be used to populate the select tag accordingly.

```
//here you have a standard js object 
//the indexes are the strings from which the label is going to get its text
//and the values for each index will be used to populate the select's options.
//How you populate this object in the first place depends on how you are getting
//the label's possible text and the corresponding options
var obj = {
    'labelValue1*':['Option1', 'Option2', 'SneakyOption', 'Option3'],
    'labelValue2*':['Option4', 'Option5', 'Option6'],
    'labelValue3*':['Option7', 'Option8', 'Option9', 'Option10']
};

//remove all children (options) currently in the select tag
//this is handy in case you intend to update the options in an event fired every time the 
//label's text changes
$('#input_302_9').empty();

//jQuery's each function (api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) iterates over
//the options (corresponding to the current text in the label) 
//appending each one to the select tag
$.each(obj[$('#field_302_9').text()], function(i, option){
    $('#input_302_9').append('<option value="' + option + '">' + option + '</option>');         
});
```

HIH